# Propositional Logic: "Ampersand In"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Text book:  "1. Symbolize each statement using the suggested notation. a) (bumper sticker) "Sometimes I Wake Up Grumpy, And Sometimes I Let Him Sleep." (W= Sometimes I wake up Grumpy, S= Sometimes I let Grumpy sleep."" That is straight from my textbook.  As of right now I think they are two separate statements. I know (think) this is not an "if-then"/"Arrow In" situation.  I don't know if I need to actually put the "and" sign in. What symbol (if any) should I use?

W, S     OR     W & S

Thank you!

Comment: The use of the term "sometimes" suggests quantification. The given statement can't be adequately represented in propositional calculus, you need predicate calculus. **Edit:** Or maybe [temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic).

Comment: @GitGud  I'm very confused by this question because it is straight out of a propositional logic book! So, as I understand it, these are two totally unrelated ideas to be separated by a comma? Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: For reference, what book is this? Imagine propositional calculus with a twist: the only connective is *and*. It's not hard to convince oneself that such a logic has very limited expressive power. By the same token (full) propositional logic isn't enough to model everything we assert in a natural language (like English). The statement in your question, I claim, is one such instance in which propositional calculus isn't enough. If the book claims it is possible to model this in propositional calculus, then I say the authors are wrong. **Edit:** What I said is assuming that W and S are as you say

Comment: @GitGud thank you. The book is "introduction to logic propositional logic revised third edition by Howard pospesel"

Comment: Please note the edit to my previous comment. Who provided $W$ and $S$, you or the author?

Comment: The book told me everything.  I'll edit the original post to be more exact

Comment: Post question edit: this is very different as "sometimes" is now incorporated in both $W$ and $S$. OK, back to the question. The book probably defined what symbol, stands in for *and*. The most common one is $\land$. Sometimes $\&$ is used. This should be explicitly mentioned in the book.

Comment: "And" is the ampersand "&" so it will be needed?

Comment: Yes, it will be needed. Care to try for an answer?

Comment: @GitGud yes thank you so much! (This is why math is not my friend....) so it would be.      1) W & S  proof is assumed  2) W   proof with "1) & out"   and 3) S proof with "2,1 & out".  something like that?

Comment: The answer is just $W\& S$, the rest that you mentioned, I simply don't understand.

Comment: @GitGud yeah. Doesn't make sense to me either. I'm glad that about that. I'm probably over thinking. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good job $\ddot \smile$